# How to get size of an image in PHP?

Tags: php, image

I want to know how many Kb,Mb an image is by PHP

Comment: The beauty of PHP is that you can find these things really easily with Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=php+file+size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function:

```
$size = filesize('image.jpg'); // Returns size in bytes
```

To find out the size in Kilobytes or Megabytes:

```
$size_in_kb = round($size / 1024, 2);
$size_in_mb = round($size / (1024 * 1024), 2);
```